# Is there an Android equivalent to the continuous flag for UISliders on iOS?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

So I am writing a Xamarin.Forms application. I have a volume slider that needs to send a volume command to a device when the value changes. Because the volume is sent over a TCP connection and must be verified by the device, and the device may not always react in real time, (and is being monitored for changes as well for two-way communication) a continuous slider is not appropriate. I only want the ValueChanged event to fire when the user lets go of the thumb. I made a custom renderer on iOS to override OnElementChanged and set the slider's continuous property to false:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null) return;

        Control.MinimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0xE6, 0x00, 0x06);
        Control.Continuous = false;
    }
```

This works like a charm. I want to do something similar for Android, however I cannot seem to figure out how to do so. Is there an equivalent flag or a function I can call on my ProgressDrawable control to get this behavior?

Comment: I have to disagree with the proposed edit to add brackets to the inverted if. I don't believe this improves readability or maintainability of the code. The intent of the inverted if is pretty clear. I think the fact that this is the default formatting from Resharper supports my own modest claim that it does not require a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So a Xamarin.Forms `Slider` on the Android is a `SeekBar`, thus you want to update the value of the `Slider` from the  `StopTrackingTouch` event vs. the `ProgressChanged` event (which is the normal behavior for the default `SliderRenderer`.

So in your custom `SliderRenderer` you can override the `ProgressChanged` event (replace the default `SliderRenderer` event) and save the ProgressValue to a class-level var.

Then override (add) `StopTrackingTouch` event and then set the Forms' `Slider.Value` to the value that you saved in the local var from the `ProgressChanged` event.

ProgressChanged: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Android.Widget.SeekBar.ProgressChanged/

StopTrackingTouch: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Android.Widget.SeekBar.StopTrackingTouch/

Comment: @bodangly no problem, happy Xammie coding